# Postgres Insert select using WITH clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert-select

I'm trying to create some entries by using an `INSERT ... SELECT ...`, but also need to use the primary key from the 1st `INSERT` operation to be included as part of a secondary operation:

```
WITH dogEntries as (INSERT INTO dog (id, another_id, name, date_created)
    SELECT public.uuid_generate_v4(), 'efd55343', name, date_created
    FROM dog WHERE owner_id = '8921571' RETURNING id as dog_uuid)

INSERT INTO dog_toys (dog_id, bed_id, status)
SELECT (SELECT dog_uuid FROM dogEntries), bed_id, status FROM dog_toys 
WHERE dog_id IN(SELECT dog_id FROM dogs WHERE another_id = '21571');
```

**public.uuid_generate_v4()** will generate the id column.

But I'm getting an error, not sure but I guess is because the `WITH dogEntries` is of course returning multiple entries.

**The error:**

> [21000] ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an
> expression

Is there any alternative of returning and iterate over the dog table inserted rows, or maybe a hint on how to traverse each of the entries from the `WITH dogEntries` statement?

Comment: `But I'm getting an error` ... So show the verbatim error message. And always your version of Postgres. And table definitions. Is `public.uuid_generate_v4()` supposed to go into `id` or `another_id`?

Comment: Updated, missed a lot of things.

Comment: Show your `CREATE TABLE` statements. Then we know where multiple rows can originate. Seems like your owners can have multiple dogs. And tell us what the statement is supposed to achieve exactly. Is it supposed to make a *single* entry in each table?

Comment: I'm trying to create copies for all the entries related to the owner_id = '8921571', then use those recently created dog entries (using its dog_id) to create dog_toys entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(SELECT dog_uuid FROM dogEntries)` in the `SELECT` list of the 2nd `INSERT` causes the error message as it returns multiple rows. It might work like this:

```sql
WITH dogentries AS (
   INSERT INTO dog (id, another_id, name, date_created)
   SELECT public.uuid_generate_v4(), 'efd55343' name, date_created
   FROM   dog
   WHERE  owner_id = 8921571
   RETURNING id AS dog_uuid
   )
INSERT INTO dog_toys (dog_id, bed_id, status)
SELECT de.dog_uuid, dt.bed_id, dt.status
FROM   dogentries de
JOIN   dog d ON d.another_id = 21571
JOIN   dog_toys dt USING (dog_id);
```

This is a shot in the dark. The objective is not entirely clear, and  table definitions are undisclosed.